# "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'" error using events when moved to backbone 0.9.10

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I has a view with this event:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#test'),
  events: {
    "change input": "test"
  },
  test: function(e) {
    console.log("test");
  }
});

var view = new View();
```

With backbone 0.9.9 it work, but with backbone 0.9.10 I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'. What I need to change to work with events on backbone 0.9.10?

I'm using this cdn's

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.10/backbone-min.js

Thanks

Comment: Is this error being triggered when .test() was invoked? It doesn't seem like test is doing anything in regards to .off(). Is there some other code that is calling .off()?

Comment: .test() is only invoked when using backbone 0.9.9. The error appear when the page load, before I do any interaction with the page.

Comment: If the error appears before any interaction with the page, the source of the problem is elsewhere. Are you able to provide the code that throws the error? (If you look at Firebug, you should be able to get a line number that throws the exception.)

Comment: I deleted all the code on my application and leave only the part with the problem. I got the same results, work with 0.9.9, doesn't work with 0.9.10. This is the error I got on chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off' backbone-min.js:38

Comment: Is it possible to put the code in JSFiddle/JSBin?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ovoroh/2/edit I removed other code on my application, but the problem persist with 0.9.10. I tried with backbone unminified, and the error appear on the line 1325. On backbone 0.9.10, that line contain this: undelegateEvents: function() {this.$el.off('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);} On backbone 0.9.9 the equivalent is undelegateEvents: function() {this.$el.unbind('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was using jquery 1.5.2 and the method off was introduced on jquery 1.7.0. Backbone 0.9.9 require that el contain the method unbind while Backbone 0.9.10 require that el contain the method off. The method unbind exist on jquery 1.5.2 and that was the reason why my code worked with backbone 0.9.9.

Comment: @Camilo : Thank you very much. I help me a lot. I was struggling through this issue from a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var Test = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "change input": "test"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.setElement($('#test'));
  },

  test: function(e) {
    alert("test");
  }
});

var test = new Test();
```

Or, this would be even better...

```
var Test = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "change input": "test"
  },

  test: function(e) {
    alert("test");
  }
});

var test = new Test({
  el: $('#test')
});
```

Comment: None of them worked. I debugged using your first example and found the problem on setElement. The first parameter of setElement is element. When I debugged, element.unbind exist, but element.off is undefined. Searching, I found that the method unbind was changed for off on backbone 0.9.10. I don't understand why element doesn't contain the new method but contain the old.

Comment: Your examples are correct. The problem was that I was using an old jquery version on my project. Thanks for your help.